# Setting Up ViewPort for Larger Vertice Values ? iPhone - OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, viewport

I am working with some larger vertice values which I have parsed from a DAE file. E.g :

```
{-79.6536, -2230.43, -213.8},{-79.6536, 2377.36, -213.8},{79.6536, 2377.36, -213.8},{79.6536, -2230.43, -213.8},{-79.6536, -2230.43, 958.953},{79.6536, -2230.43, 958.953},{79.6536, 2377.36, 958.953},{-79.6536, 2377.36, 958.953},...
```

My question is what changes do I need to make to the setting up of my viewport in order to accomodate these larger vertices ? I currently have the following :

```
- (void)setupView
{       
// Set up the window that we will view the scene through
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

// switch to the projection matrix and setup our 'camera lens'
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    

// switch to model mode and set our background color
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
}
```

However when I run the code, I just get a screen filled with white - I presume because my object is zoomed in to an extreme degree.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glScalef(max_s, max_s, max_s);`

Where

> max_s = 2.0 / max(max(Xi) - min(Xi), max(Yi) - min(Yi), max(Zi) - min(Zi))

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - use glScale where ? And what is Xi, Yi etc ?

Comment: You need to find the minimum and maximum values in all three directions. Then you need to scale the model before rendering.